# Limit of holomorphic and bounded functions that can be extended to a ball

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of bounded and holomorphic functions on the annulus $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\, 1<|z|<2\}$ such that each $f_n$ can be holomorphically extended to $B_2(0) = \{ z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\, |z|<2\}$. Let $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to a holomorphic and bounded function $f$ on $A$. Show that $f$ can be holomorphically extended to $B_2(0)$.

My attempt: We find a sequence $(g_n)$ of holomorphic functions on $B_2(0)$ with $f_n = g_n|_A$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. As each $f_n$ is bounded, we have $|g_n| = |f_n| \leq M$ on $A$. In addition, as holomorphic functions are continuous, we infer $m:=\max_{z\in \overline{B_{3/2}(0)}} |g_n(z)|<\infty$. Together, this yields $|g_n|\leq \max\{m, M\}$ on $B_2(0)$, i.e. each $g_n$ is bounded on $B_2(0)$. If I could now show that $(g_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to the supremum norm on $B_2(0)$ (I achieved to show compact convergence on $B_2(0)$ by using the maximum modulus principle, but according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057731/equivalence-of-compact-and-uniform-convergence-for-sequences-of-holomorphic-func), this is not equivalent to uniform convergence), there would be a holomorphic and bounded limit $g: B_2(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, as the set of holomorphic and bounded functions on a domain of $\mathbb{C}$ is Banach. But then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$ and $f_n = g_n|_A$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $A$. By uniqueness of limits, $f=g$ on $A$. Thus, $g$ is the desired holomorphic extension of $f$ to $B_2(0)$. How can I show that $(g_n)$ is Cauchy?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by $B_2(0)$?  Normally this stands for the open ball, but calling it "the disk" suggests you are considering the "closed ball".

Comment: I mean the open ball, I have edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried using the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: Yes, but I only achieved to show that the supremum of $|g_n(z)-g_m(z)|$ for $z\in K$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ where $K\subset B_2(0)$ is an arbitrary compact set, as the functions $g_n$ are not defined on $\partial B_2(0)$.

Comment: $$
  \sup_{|z|\leq1}|g_n(z)-g_m(z)| \leq \sup_{|z|=3/2}|g_n(z)-g_m(z)| = \sup_{|z|=3/2}|f_n(z)-f_m(z)|
  $$

Comment: And then you estimate $\sup_{|z| = 3/2}$ by $\sup_{z\in A}$ and use the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ on $A$?

Comment: another way is to remember that a holomorphic function in an annulus can be extended to the inner disc iff the negative power part of its Laurent series is null iff $\int_C f(z)z^ndz=0, n \ge 0$ where $C$ is a circle in the annulus parallel to the boundary circles (eg $|z| =3/2$ here will do); uniform convergence of $f_m$ on the circle $C$ then gives that for $f$

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments by Ruy, we have using the maximum modulus principle
\begin{align}
\sup_{|z|\leq 1} |g_n(z)-g_m(z)| &\leq \sup_{|z|\leq 3/2} |g_n(z)-g_m(z)| \leq \sup_{|z|= 3/2} |g_n(z)-g_m(z)|\\
&= \sup_{|z|=3/2} |f_n(z)-f_m(z)|\leq \sup_{z\in A} |f_n(z)-f_m(z)|<\epsilon,
\end{align}
as $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A$ and convergent sequences are Cauchy. Then
\begin{equation}
\sup_{z\in B_2(0)} |g_n(z)-g_m(z)|\leq \max\Bigg\{ \sup_{|z|\leq 1} |g_n(z)-g_m(z)|,\,\, \sup_{z\in A} |g_n(z)-g_m(z)|\Bigg\}<\epsilon,
\end{equation}
so we indeed have that $(g_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to the supremum norm on $B_2(0)$.